# Why does Atom documentation use CoffeeScript, but generate packages in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, atom-editor

I'm trying to create my first Atom package and there is one thing that I'm confused about:

The [Atom Documentation](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.15.0/View) provides examples in CoffeeScript while the default installed [Package Generator](https://github.com/atom/package-generator) generates JavaScript code. Why isn't there a uniform choice? Or is one of them outdated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Atom is slowly moving away from CofeeScript and has the mantra of 'no new CoffeeScript code'. This is explained by Nathan Sobo in the ChangeLog podcast episode 241, entitled '[The Story of Atom](https://changelog.com/podcast/241)'.

Most mention of this question on the Atom discussions tends to point towards [this topic](https://discuss.atom.io/t/why-coffeescript/131) which, while not official announcement, covers much of the ground. The CoffeeScript issue has also been addressed in the FAQs by linking to Kevin Sawicki's comment [here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/is-coffeescript-required-for-developing-plug-ins/65/3), which explains that CoffeeScript is not required to create atom packages.

Comment: Ah.. well, I guess it's kind of impossible to have a quick transition in such a big open source project. I hope they update documentation soon then :)

Comment: As far as I know, Atom also transpiles packages written in TypeScript automatically, so you can actually use all three.

Comment: I understand @idleberg, but learning techniques which are already deprecated is not what I'd like..